# Warning in java changes with the scope of cast

Tags: java

When I compile a program in java containing this  :

```
ch = (char) ch - 32;
```

the terminal shows :

```
    incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to char
                    ch = (char) ch - 32;
                                   ^
    1 error
```

but this works

```
    ch = (char) (ch - 32);
```

why is this happening?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ch is a char but 32 is a literal integer, integers are defined with 32 bits that char will be promoted to int in order to do that operation and  the result is not a char anymore....

Comment: In the second case, you take an integer (`ch-32`) and cast it to char. That cast tells the compiler: "Do not bother me with warning, I know what I am doing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

```
ch = (char) ch - 32;
```

is the same as

```
ch = ( (char) ch ) - 32;
```

As in:

```
ch = ch - 32;
```

Which first turns `ch` into an int value. To subtract 32. Resulting in an int value. Which doesn't fit into a char (easily). Thus the compiler error.

One way around that: make sure that the cast applies to the result of the operation, not to the first operand.

```
 ch = (char) ( ch - 32 );
```

Comment: You might note that this error only occurs when the compiler cannot verify that the value will fit.  `char ch=32;` compiles fine even though `32` is an int because the compiler "knows" it will fit.  `char ch=65535;` compiles, but `char ch=65536;` does not.

Comment: Correct. My answer could be a bit clearer. Will rework it... When I have a real keyboard at hand. Which might take a while.